# Потоки и локальный кэш

Tags: java

Встретился пример, показывающий работу ключевого слова volatile:

```
public class VolatileDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new VolatileDemo().start();
    }
    //----------------------------------------------

    private boolean btExit = false; //без volatile

    // запуск потоков
    public void start() {
        new Thread(gui).start();
        System.out.println("gui thread started");
        new Thread(game).start();
        System.out.println("game thread started");
    }

    // поток для интерфейса
    Runnable gui = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000); // типа пользователь общается с GUI и выходит из игры
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
            btExit = true; // поток game не видит это изменение без volatile
            System.out.println("gui thread finished");
        }
    };

    // поток для игры
    Runnable game = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long count = 0;
            while (!btExit) {
                // без volatile этот цикл крутится бесконечно
                count++;
                // если раскомментировать строку ниже то цикл завершится!!!
//              System.out.println("loop ended without volatile!");
            }
            System.out.println("game thread finished");
        }
    };
}
```

Запускаем потоки, поток gui отрабатывает и изменяет переменную btExit на true, поток game изменение переменной btExit не видит и цикл уходит в вечность.

Как я понял потоки считали себе в локальный кэш переменную btExit и дальнейшие операции чтения/записи проводили из своего локального кэша и у каждого потока было свое значение переменной.

Ключевое слово volatile может эту ситуацию исправить, потоки будут работать с актуальным значением переменной в основной памяти.

Вопрос: если я не применяя volatile к переменной btExit в цикле потока game выведу на печать что-нибудь, либо вызову Thread.sleep()  и т.п., то завершение работы потока будет аналогичной с применением volatile(он завершится при btExit = true), почему?

Comment: Я могу предположить, что при выводе на печать или любом другом действии, которое использует кеш процессора - произойдёт вытеснение переменной из кеша (т.е. запись его значения в память), а при повторной проверке - его повторная загрузка из памяти. И там мы столкнёмся с другим приколом многотредовых систем, который вульгарно называется "кто последний - тот и папа": два треда попробуют модифицировать в памяти одно значение. Кто последний - у того и получится.

Comment: Наверное стоит добавить, что кеш не процессора даже, а кеш разных уровней/ядер. Иначе возникает вопрос: почему процессор смотрит в кеш и видит разные значения без volatile)

Comment: Потому что на входе/выходе в `synchronize` блок/метод, локальный кэш сбрасывается

Comment: @AntonShchyrov нашел подтверждение Ваших слов. Когда поток game вызывает метод println переменной System.out. происходит обновление переменной btExit, т.к. метод println содержит синхронизированный блок.